# Can IIS and NGINX scan Custom Headers and Accept/Deny Request Depending on Filter?

Tags: linux, iis-8, nginx-config

I want to accept/deny requests depending on Http request custom headers. Is there any option available in both IIS and NGINX?

I think IIS has  but NGINX??????

Comment: For IIS you should be able to use URL Rewrite module. NGINX does have something similar, https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: I think rewriting is different than request header filtering. @LexLi

Comment: No. You can use URL Rewrite module to replace request filtering most of the time.

Comment: @LexLi How would I achieve my question using rewrite? I need to check if customHeader1 = xyz then accept otherwise deny request?

Comment: For IIS, it is rather simple to return a custom response from your rules, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114236/in-iis-rewrite-rules-is-it-possible-to-return-a-customresponse-statuscode-with To check custom header of the request, add a condition. On NGINX, the same can be easily achieved via return directive.

Comment: @LexLi above url applies regex on url. This does not answer my question. I need to look into request header (NOT URL) and then deny/accept request.

Comment: "To check custom header of the request, add a condition."

Answer (score 0):

URL rewrite inbound rule can deny request based on request header. For example, if your custom request header is AuthHeader. Then you only need to add a condition pattern for{HTTP_AuthHeader}.

The sample deny rule would looks like this.

```
<rule name="deny rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_AuthHeader}" pattern="jokies" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
```

As you can see, IIS return 504 when the request header AuthHeader=jokies.
[image]

IIS return 200 if the AuthHeader doesn't match jokies

[image]

Of course, you can develop and inject your custom httpmodule to customize the request header filter.

Comment: great, but can you tell me how can I achieve same in NGINX?

Comment: I think its almost the same.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223733/how-to-make-nginx-redirect-based-on-the-value-of-a-header.  identify the request HTTP_custom header， then return 401 status.